# Can I run ordinal regression without recoding or should I recode the combined variable?

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data, likert

I have four questions representing one variable called work family conflict. They are all ordinal. And I added all the items and made it one variable.

After adding them up, I got code ranging from 1 to 16. Now 16 means high conflict and 1 means low. I have to to run the regression, how can I do it.  Work family conflict is independent variable and my dependent variable is self reported health which is a likert scale.

- Should I recode and categorized it to high, medium and low and run the ordinal regression?
- Or can I run the ordinal regression without categorizing?
- Is it right to run the ordinal regression when dependent variable has likert scale?

Comment: You can do it both way. Your dependent variable is ordinal and you have a categorical independent variable.

Comment: If you have enough cases then leave it as 0 to 16 (you did mean that, not 1 to 16?). Why waste data?

Comment: I am not confused about whether it should be 0 or 1, I am confused as to how I can run the regression with. If I run the regression I will get value for each from 1 to 16 but I don't want that. I want one value that is for the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Summing or averaging ordinal variables is debateable, but proceeding anyway, ordinal regression (PLUM) gives you a threshold coefficient for each level, but you still get only one coefficient for your independent covariate.